# SQL - best practices

Tags: sql

I am about to develop a small cms\forum. Multiple customers are going to have there own access where the customers can communicate white them.

What is best practices- to make separate SQL db to each customer's cms data or one big to contain all the customers data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Database standards & best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776031/sql-server-database-standards-best-practices)

Comment: I think [“multi-tenancy”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) is the technical term you are looking for. Much too large a topic for Stack Overflow which is aimed at *narrow* laser-focused programming-technicality problem-solution pairs.

Comment: I would **most definitely** vote for **ONE** database and handle the customers inside your database. **DO NOT** create a separate database for each customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I cannot comment, so I can only type here.

It is strange that you would like to have separate database for each customer and it seems impossible to manage multiple db for just one purpose or function. For example, how could you identify which db belong to which customer? Also, do you expect to have many resource to allocate to each customer? a db simply waste if the customer is not active.

So, I suggest you to use one db to manage all the customers data which is normal solution.